# VBscript gives out of range error with arrays within loop but not with arrays outside

Tags: arrays, csv, vbscript, msdn

I am getting a "Subscript out of range error" on line 23 of my code. I am opening and reading a .csv file and trying to return the data of the last line. The input information looks like this:

```
Control Unit
Date,Time,Seconds,V1,V2,V3,V4,
07/12/2013 ,11:27:21 ,0 ,Closed ,Closed ,Closed ,Closed ,
07/12/2013 ,11:27:22 ,1 ,Closed ,Closed ,Closed ,Closed ,
```

Outside of the while loop if I say WScript.Echo = strValues(3) then it echoes the right data, but if I try the same thing within the loop, then I simply get an out of range error for anything other than strValues(0). I don't understand this because if I check the strValues array once the while loop is complete I can call any of the 7 elements.

```
Option Explicit
Dim first, secnd 
Dim fso, inputFile 
Dim strSource, strLine, strValues
Const ForReading = 1

'Create the file system object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Initialize a few items
strSource = "C:\Testing\data.csv"

'Open the source file to read it
Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strSource,ForReading)

'Read the file line by line
Do while not inputFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = inputFile.ReadLine
    'Split the line on the comma into an array
    strValues = Split(strLine, ",")
    'Check if the dq number matches
    first = strValues(0)
    'secnd = strValues(3) 'here it tells me its out of range
Loop
WScript.Echo strLine  'once the loop is over it gives me the values just fine
Wscript.Echo strValues(1)
secnd = strValues(3) 'this gives no error
'Close the file
inputFile.Close

'Clean up
Set inputFile = Nothing                                                                           
Set fso = Nothing
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your test file does not contain a comma, thus the array `strValues` has a single entry only during the first iteration.

place an extra `strLine = inputFile.ReadLine` before the `do while` loop and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: +1, although I think `.SkipLine` would be more appropriate when he's ignoring that line anyway.